# Using where clause in an if statement

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the big nerd ranch's book to learn iOS programming in swift. One of their examples has me typing the following code:

```
if let text = textField.text where !text.isEmpty {
    celsiusLabel.text = text
}
else {
    celsiusLabel.text = "???"
}
```

This was working fine a few weeks ago, but now I've upgraded to swift 3 and it seems to have stopped compiling. What's the correct and idiomatic way to write this if statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was tweaked as per [Proposal SE-0099, Restructuring Condition Clauses](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0099-conditionclauses.md), which was implemented in Swift 3.

```
if let text = textField.text, !text.isEmpty {
    celsiusLabel.text = text
}
else {
    celsiusLabel.text = "???"
}
```

The `if` statement is already in itself like a `where` clause, so they found it more suitable to just require a comma.

Comment: Fantastic. Works great. Thanks for the explanation as well.